# Model doesn't subdivide very nicely

Tags: modifiers

I'm making scissors. I made the two parts with two different methods.

**File attached:**

[image]

1. For the green part, I made an svg file, imported it and extruded it. However, now when I apply subdivisions and I'm not getting sharp edges.
2. For the white part, I made the svg file, imported it and  extruded it. This time, I selected the inner ring and the outer edges and separated both cuts with the Boolean modifier. I then used <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to fill it. If I apply the subdivision modifier it just fills the inner hole.

How can I fix the subdivision modifier for both scissor blades?

[image]

[image]

[image]

### New model made

[image]

Comment: To give you a god answer we will need a wire frame to see what the sub' is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Give the subdivision modifier squares and triangles to work with and it will do what it should. You have a real big mess of faces in the mesh. If you make faces with four vertices it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to bevel a bit the edges you want to make sharp, or add extra loop cuts. Basically, if you add more geometry will constrain the subdivision, and will look sharper. You can also add the ammount of "crease" on the edges you want sharper: under edit mode, select those edges, press N for right lateral panel, under "transform" look for "edge data" and increase the "crease" until looks like you want. Those creased edges will look red under viewport material shader.[image: crease edges]

Comment: @ MCunha can u plz try with my model. And send me the image or .gif file

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a look

Answer (score -1):

to correctly model your model: import reference image as a plane. change to ortographic view (press 5 then press 7 with numeric keypad, not the numbers of text keyboard), add a plane, move to where you want to start your draw. Enter edit mode. Select and extrude edges and/or vertices to match the draw (see image, extruding and refining edge position, all faces of new object are quads - 4 edge polygon). when your are done, if will have a projection of your model on a plane, with pure quad-faces. Exit top view, select all your faces, extrude in Z-axis to give depth. Then select vertices where you want them to be at different Z-levels. Select edges to be sharp and increase de "crease" in the transform panel. Perform subdivision surface and add extra loop cuts if needed to constrain geometry. Exit edit mode, Press T, under tool, select shading to smooth.
In the following link, is a Blend file, with one of the blades retopologized by me, you see how I performed a pure quad-mesh, and I do the other blade:https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7t43CPM6VA-RzFKYVJLSmlkQ1E/view?usp=sharing
In this tutorial, you might see a guy doing a scissor:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D8VmGtBebHs
here you see a guy working with reference planes, doing a pure quad-mesh:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zOxD-T6nLys
[image: edge_refine]

Comment: I have attach my model image. Thanks u said u will redo my model. But i want to learn. I dont want to have ready made model from others. As im a learner i want to know where im going wrong and right. I want to learn good from u good expert and make new models.

Comment: one more thing, don't perform boollean modifiers, unless you really need! Just manually extrude your faces and vertices around the holes you want to cut! The boolean modifier (or other modifiers) might mess with the number of edges of your faces, doing a N-gon mesh. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for ur brief reply. I have made the model and above my file is attached (New model made ----.blend file). I have made the model but not satisfied with it. I have made it look just a general view. In the model i was unable to make the cutting edge of the scissor. And the twist of the handle.

Comment: Hi @atek, for the cutting edge, or the twist of the blade, you need to select vertices or edges and scale/translate or rotate them to a place desired. Example: one part of your scissor (blade+handle) has always same depth/width (like a cube), now you have to rescale some edges, so you get areas thinner than others. If you see the model I've uploaded yesterday, you see that the edges on the blade are thinner. Also check that I didn't increase the crease level for all the loopcuts, Just the parts I wanted to be sharp

Comment: for a faster way, you can apply a boolean modifier like this: duplicate Cube and Cube.001 and move them to layer 2. After that, you do a Boollean difference between Cube and the copy of Cube.001, and a boollean between Cube.001 and the copy of Cube. When you have the desired effect, apply the boolean modifiers and delect the copies that are on layer 2, than you just need to resize the edges of the twist of the handle.